# file_put_contents() and flock() error 'out of free disk space '

Tags: php

I run this test script

```
<?php
function LockData($file,$locker=LOCK_EX){
    static $streams=array();
    $md=md5($file);

    if(empty($streams[$md])){
        $streams[$md]=fopen($file,'a+');
    }
    $i=0;
    do{
        $lock=flock($streams[$md],$locker);
    }while(!$lock && ++$i<=3);

    return $lock;
}

function ReadData($file){
    if(is_file($file)){
        $lock=LockData($file);
        if(!$lock) return false;

        $data=@file_get_contents($file);

        if(!empty($data)){
            return unserialize(str_replace('<?die;?>',"",$data));
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function WriteData($file,$data){
    file_put_contents($file,'<?die;?>'.serialize($data));

    LockData($file,LOCK_UN);
}

$fp=ReadData($file="test.txt");

if(!$fp)$fp=array();
print_r($fp);
$fp[]="2";
WriteData($file,$fp);
```

And if I use the LockData() function I have a error "Warning: file_put_contents() [function.file-put-contents]: Only 0 of 26 bytes written, possibly out of free disk space"
Don't understand this...

Comment: Well, how much hard drive space is free?

Comment: 120 Gigabytes...And this error displays only if I use LockData()/flock

Comment: I don't see where `file_put_contents()` is used within `LockData()` are you sure that's where the warning is coming from?

Comment: If I remove the `LockData()` function, from `WriteData()` and `ReadData()`, all works fine... Platform windows 7, on Linux all works without errors...

Answer (score 0):

The problam was in windows, because flock() under win use blocking as "per file handler", but under Linux it works as "per proccess".
So, in one script I have two fopen(). First in LockData() and second in file_put_contents(), and second can't write data into file, because file handler is locked (under Win).